# Change (local) in SQL Management Studio 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

During the installation of SQL Management Studio 2008, I set up the default server to be (local).

Now, I want to either change this to (local)/mySubdirectoryName, or create a new one that is located at (local)/mySubdirectoryName, but I cannot see where this can be done.

Is there a way that I can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to **change** the name of a SQL Server instance, you need to reinstall it. There's no other way to do this.

So in your case, your best bet would be to probably just install a new instance of SQL Server under a new specific instance name.

Comment: Does sp_addserver not change the name as well?